# Power output in an Arduino using analogwrite()

Tags: power, software

I understand that using arduinowrite(anynumberoutput,0-255) will give me a average voltage output x/255 *5v to be outputted from Arduino.

Hence, when this question ask,

> An PWM is generated by the command analogWrite(pin,100). What is the power supplied thru 250ohms resistor.

I have assumed the answer to be (100/255*5)^2/250 but the answer is different. It is 39mW. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Would [arduino.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Thanks all for correcting me where to post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are mis-applying \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$. I don't think that formula is valid when \$V\$ is the *average* of a time-varying waveform. I think it is only valid for the *instantaneous* voltage and power.

In order to find the average power in this case, you can frst calculate the power that would be dissipated in the resistor by a steady 5V DC, and then multiply *that* value by the PWM factor, \$\frac{100}{255}\$.

---

Consider, if the output voltage was +5V half the time, and -5V half the time. The average voltage in that case would be zero, but the average power would be 100mW.

---

P.S.:

If that was homework, I would ask my teacher, "What do you mean, 'Power delivered *through* the resistor?'" Delivered *through* the resistor *to* what other component?... Oh! I get it! You mean power dissipated *by* the resistor!

Comment: Haha Thanks for all your help!